# Attempted to assign to readonly property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am getting exception with message `Attempted to assign to readonly property` when I try to assign a value to property defined in a service.

My Cordova project uses AngularJS. Here is a part of my code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MyApp.controllers')
.service('LoginOrigin', function () {
        return {
            origin: undefined
        };
    });

angular.module('MyApp.controllers')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', 'LoginOrigin',
        function($scope, $http, $rootScope, LoginOrigin) {

            $scope.signUp = function() {
                // ...
                // exception gets thrown on the following line
                LoginOrigin.origin = 'menu';
                // ...
            };
        }
    ]);
```

Why I am getting the exception and how could I chnage the code to fix the issue?

Comment: I ran your code and I don't seem to be getting any exceptions: http://jsfiddle.net/0f9kfj5c/2/

Comment: @SteveLang hmm, thank you, it's interesting. I guess I have to figure out what makes the difference in my case: Cordova, iOS Simulator or something else.

Comment: @Bobrovsky this is very similar to an exception we see on iOS in our app. It seems to be related to `'use strict'` in Angular/our app code. Googling around 'use strict angular assign readonly property' yields many similar Safari issues.. Hope this is useful.

Comment: how did you solved this issue?